# Why is postresql sorting without order by?

Tags: postgresql, sorting

see the super simple sql below.

```
   select   doc_type, translation
   from     document, labels
   where    labels.id=document.doc_type

[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Merge Join",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Async Capable": false,
      "Join Type": "Inner",
      "Startup Cost": 338397.68,
      "Total Cost": 614895.84,
      "Plan Rows": 18432774,
      "Plan Width": 34,
      "Actual Startup Time": 0.011,
      "Actual Total Time": 0.012,
      "Actual Rows": 0,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Inner Unique": false,
      "Merge Cond": "(labels.id = document.doc_type)",
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Sort",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Startup Cost": 82.93,
          "Total Cost": 86.2,
          "Plan Rows": 1310,
          "Plan Width": 34,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0.011,
          "Actual Total Time": 0.011,
          "Actual Rows": 0,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Sort Key": [
            "labels.id"
          ],
          "Sort Method": "quicksort",
          "Sort Space Used": 25,
          "Sort Space Type": "Memory",
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Relation Name": "labels",
              "Alias": "labels",
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Total Cost": 15.1,
              "Plan Rows": 1310,
              "Plan Width": 34,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0.008,
              "Actual Total Time": 0.008,
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 1
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Node Type": "Sort",
          "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Async Capable": false,
          "Startup Cost": 338314.76,
          "Total Cost": 345350.17,
          "Plan Rows": 2814164,
          "Plan Width": 2,
          "Actual Startup Time": 0,
          "Actual Total Time": 0,
          "Actual Rows": 0,
          "Actual Loops": 0,
          "Sort Key": [
            "document.doc_type"
          ],
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Seq Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Async Capable": false,
              "Relation Name": "document",
              "Alias": "document",
              "Startup Cost": 0,
              "Total Cost": 36857.64,
              "Plan Rows": 2814164,
              "Plan Width": 2,
              "Actual Startup Time": 0,
              "Actual Total Time": 0,
              "Actual Rows": 0,
              "Actual Loops": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 0.114,
    "Triggers": [],
    "Execution Time": 0.033
  }
]
```

Using explain analyze i can see postgres is doing a sort yet i don't ask for it (there is no order by). How may i prevent postgres to do sort when it is not required ? So suppose there are 2 records in table document getting this

1, "man"

2, "woman"

is ok as well as having

2, "woman"

1, "man"

On this super simple sql this is not that a problem to have this sort but first i want to understand why that happens and on huge tables i guess this can be costly for something you don't even want

regards,
John

Comment: For future questions, please post the plan in `text` form (`explain (analyze, format text)` the JSON format is not intended to be read by humans

Comment: This is a side effect of the chosen join strategy, and you cannot depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is not just used to fulfill an ORDER BY.  Sorting is also a way to bring equal values next to each other.  That can be useful for joining, aggregating, or uniquifying. Specifically, your plan is doing a merge join.  A merge join requires each input to be ordered by the join key.

Why is it doing a merge join rather than a hash join? I don't know, but clearly your stats are deranged.  It probably has something to do with that, and anyway it is not worth trying to micromanage such a situation.